# global npm package: 'exports' is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, package.json

I am trying to create a simple node.js cli tool called `convertxml`. I have defined the `bin` field in my `package.json` and ran `npm link`.

When I run it, I am getting the following error when I run `convertxml` in powershell/cmd.

[image: error message image]

using the following package.json:

[image: package.json picture]

with the following tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true, 
    "target": "ES5", 
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "jsx": "preserve", 
    "module": "ES6", 
    "moduleResolution": "node", 
    "resolveJsonModule": true, 
    "noEmit": true, 
    "isolatedModules": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

The weird thing is that when I run `node ./converter.js` it runs perfectly.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe `"convertxml":"./converter.js"` should be `"convertxml":"node ./converter.js"`?

Comment: It looks like you're starting the .js file with Microsoft JScript instead of Node.js. If you add `#!/usr/bin/env node` in converter.js at the first line, NPM will make sure that the JS-file gets started in Node instead of JScript.